# Why does this piece of code overflow at 255?

Tags: atmega328, eeprom, variables

Im having a problem where i got unsinged long variable and i need to increment it in eeprom everytime setup starts and it overflows at `255` back to `0`.

```cpp
unsigned long NumberOfBoots = 0UL;
#define INFO_NUMBER_OF_BOOTS_ADDR 0
#define INFO_NUMBER_OF_BOOTS_LEN sizeof(NumberOfBoots)

// in setup
EEPROM.get(INFO_NUMBER_OF_BOOTS_ADDR, NumberOfBoots);
EEPROM.update(INFO_NUMBER_OF_BOOTS_ADDR, ++NumberOfBoots);
```

My guess is that its due to `Update()` fuction. Any ideas?

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROMUpdate

Comment: And also https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROMPut

Comment: @DaveNewton  
Thanks, so its actual limitation of Update function. I will use put. Thank you both